# Yii: override getDbConnection method and set CDbConnection from the master db to a slave db

Tags: yii

For some reason I cant switch the db connection to save data in the secondary dbs.

db tables from the main db:

I have a `website model` class that stores data about a `website`.

`WebsiteM extends Website wich extends CActiveRecord`

I have a `url model` class that stores data about a `url`.

`UrlM extends Url wich extends CActiveRecord`

Each `url` belongs to a `website`; each `url` has a `FK` named `website_id` that tells the website that it belongs to;

Because the `website model` and `url model` are changing daily, I wrote for each model a `new class` that extends them, like `websiteM extends website` and `urlM extends url` and this way when I regenerate the models using `gii`, my enhancements are always saved.

db table from the slave db:

I have a `slave url model` class that stores data about a `url` in one of the slave active dbs.

The `slave url model` is the same as the `main url model`;

It's like this: `UrlSlaveM extends UrlSlave wich extends HActiveRecord wich extends CActiveRecord`

At some point, I try to switch to a secondary db, by using `relations` to find out the `id` of the `db` that I need to switch to, after new class instance like:

`$model_urlSlave_new = new UrlSlaveM();`

`$model_urlSlave_new::$server_id = $model_url->websiteM_relation->database_id;`

This should work, but it does not. This is where the action happens, this is where the connection should switch:

```
class HActiveRecord extends CActiveRecord {

    public static $server_id = 2;
    public static $master_db;

    public function getDbConnection() {
        self::$master_db = Yii::app()->{"db" . self::$server_id};
        if (self::$master_db instanceof CDbConnection) {
            self::$master_db->setActive(true);
            return self::$master_db;
        }
        else
            throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii', 'Active Record requires a "db" CDbConnection application component.'));
    }

}
```

settings in `main.php`

```
'db' => array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dvc',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
        'db2' => array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dvc2',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'tablePrefix' => '',
            'class' => 'CDbConnection'          // DO NOT FORGET THIS!
        ),
        'db1' => array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dvc1',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'tablePrefix' => '',
            'class' => 'CDbConnection'          // DO NOT FORGET THIS!
        ),
```

Comment: You defined db connections in config components array?

Comment: yes i did, will udate now info

Comment: It gives you an error, or simply not working?

Comment: well, it always saved data in te main db and the first slave db; i cant save data to the 2nd slave db

Comment: what is really strange: i have done this many times and it worked, but since when i have this new class on top of the standard model class, the code, it fails to work

Comment: its like when it extends, somehow, my getDbConnection method is eaten :))

Comment: Try to rename it getDbConnection(). Should work.

Comment: why should i rename it? this method needs to be there in order to set the connection

Comment: try putting a 'die("on my getDbConnection");' to validate that it arrives.

Comment: i did , and nothing happens; it is strange because it saves data to the first db always

Comment: Try to rename to public function getfirstDbConnection() and so on. This function can be extended in model. `public function getDbConnection()
    {
        return self::getfirstDbConnection();
    }` This will work definetly.

Comment: i also did that, nothing happened; i suspected that i had a duplicate model also, but it was not the case

Comment: are you sure that you model extends of 'HActiveRecord'?

Comment: Then idk. It works for me. I have 2 db's , 2 functions in MyActiverecord and extend in models connection which i need. Really it work, so if you doing same  -  seems its db problems, not yii.

Comment: strange, i will put my code on git later today to see who finds the bug

Comment: so, I found the bug, don't know why it is a bug, but it is; i had to move the code from hactiverecord to my main model file and now it works; strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

The following code was moved to the main model class and the `hactiverecord` class was deleted.

```
public static $server_id = 2;
    public static $master_db;

    public function getDbConnection() {
        self::$master_db = Yii::app()->{"db" . self::$server_id};
        if (self::$master_db instanceof CDbConnection) {
            self::$master_db->setActive(true);
            return self::$master_db;
        }
        else
            throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii', 'Active Record requires a "db" CDbConnection application component.'));
    }
```

it works. tested.